# Cannot access to x2go client with same credentials more than once

Tags: linux, windows, x2go

I am trying to access via x2go client to the server (Linux system) through my laptop (windows). It seems that I could once, but for the following times it seems that there are authentication problems.

It returns the message:

> "The remote proxy closed the connection while negotiating the session.
> This may be due to the wrong authentication credentials passed to the
> server."

I am using the same password, though. Ang clue on how to fix this? Thanks for

Answer (score 1):

Check the log file in ~/.x2go/C-/session.log.  I've found it usually gives some more information.  After that, check the system log files.

Not an answer but hopefully points you at the underlying issue.

Comment: I will try and I will let you updated. Could you please suggest where to test this command?